# Работа с ListBox

Tags: delphi

Здравствуйте, появилась проблема с работой с `ListBox`'ми.

В программе даются два `ListBox`'а, четыре кнопки. Первые две кнопки перетаскивают по одной строке из одного списка в другой (1->2 и 2->1 соответственно). Вторые две кнопки перетаскивают выделенную группу аналогично первым двум кнопкам.
Проблема в следующем:

1. Как сделать так, чтобы программа проверила, выделили ли мы какой-либо элемент в списке или нет? Если не выделили, то кнопка для этого списка просто не работает.
2. Вообще, как задавать проверки для того, что мы выделили строку в списке, не обращаясь к процедуре `ListBox Clik`, чтобы все исключительно работало через кнопки?

Comment: `ListBox1.SelCount` - количество выделенных записей. Условие проверки должно опираться на него.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListBox1.ItemIndex` вернет индекс выбранной строки и `-1`, если ни одна строка не выбрана, для одиночного выделения.

Для множественного выделения (`MultiSelect = true`) можно проверить, выделена ли та или иная строка, воспользовавшись свойством  `Selected[Index: integer]`. Для выделенных строк это значение будет равно `true`.

Например, так можно выявить все выделенные строки:

```
  for i := 0 to ListBox1.Count - 1 do
    if ListBox1.Selected[i]  then begin
      // делаем что-то  с выделенной строкой
    end;
```

И, конечно, как сказал [[@KiTE](/users/2084/kite)](/users/2084/kite), `SelCount` покажет кол-во выбранных строк.

Comment: а можно про одиночное выделение поподробнее? 

То есть, мы должны сначала задать 

ListBox1.SelCount=1 then то, что мы собираемся делать?

Comment: Да, можно так. Если мы хотим именно отличить одиночное выделение от множественного.